# Firebase Firestore with Expo v37

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Hi I am using Expo v37 and Firebase SDK v7.9.0

My imports look like this:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
import config from '~/config';

firebase.initializeApp(
  {
    apiKey: config.firebaseApiKey,
    authDomain: config.firebaseAuthDomain,
    databaseURL: config.firebaseDatabaseURL,
    projectId: config.firebaseProjectId,
    storageBucket: config.firebaseStorageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: config.firebaseMessagingSenderId,
    appId: config.firebaseAppId,
    measurementId: config.firebaseMeasurementId,
  },
);

export default firebase;
export const database = firebase.firestore();
```

I am receiving the following error when trying to use the firestore module:

```
TypeError: firebase.INTERNAL.registerService is not a function. (In 'firebase.INTERNAL.registerService('firestore', function (app) {
      return new Firestore(app);
    }, shallowCopy(firestoreNamespace))', 'firebase.INTERNAL.registerService' is undefined)

Query.prototype.validateDisjunctiveFilterElements
    index.cjs.js:21630:9
registerFirestore
    App.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:179870:25
<unknown>
    App.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:179873:20
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
verb
    tslib.js:196:33
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<unknown>
    App.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:155308:14
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<unknown>
    App.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:138892:53
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<unknown>
    App.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:133762:26
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    App.js:6
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:201:45
downloadUrlHandler
    index.cjs.js:1515:5
```

If I remove the firestore import everything works correctly.

Is this a bug with Expo or the Firebase SDK? Does anyone have Firestore working with Expo 37?

Comment: I have installed firebase with npm and I added those imports to default expo blank project created with `expo init` and I can run this project with no issue. Can you share little more code maybe there is something wrong with configuration or initializing firestore?

Comment: @vitooh I have added the config code. Like I said though, if I comment out the firestore import the project runs fine, as soon as I try to import it I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Installing node modules with Yarn seems to fix this issue...